# norm of Ricci curvature and Einstein manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

If ‎$ ‎||Ric||‎^{2}=‎\frac{S‎^{2}‎}{‎n‎}‎‎‎ $‎can be concluded ‎$ ‎Ric=‎\frac{S}{n}‎‎ $‎? where Ric is Ricci tensor and S is scalar ‎curvature.‎

Comment: I think it is wrong. $Ric$ is tensor, how tensor equal to scalar ?

Comment: By "$Ric = \frac{S}{n}$", do you mean $Ric = \frac{S}{n} g$? In any case (assuming the norm is the pointwise norm, not the $L^{2}$ norm), I suspect "no": The type of counterexample I'd seek is a product of Einstein metrics of differing Einstein constants.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo mistake. It should be Ric=S/n g

Answer (score 2):

It is correct because
‎‎$ ‎||Ric-‎\frac{S}{‎n‎}g||‎^{2}=||Ric||‎^{2}-‎\frac{S‎^{2}‎}{‎n‎} ‎=0‎$‎.